# I am facing a problem regarding limiting my rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    cursor c is
    select book.bookid,book.title,publisher.publishername,
    author.firstname,author.lastname from book 
    inner join publisher on 
    book.publisherid  =publisher.publisherid
    inner join author on book.author_id=author.authorid
    order by book.title
    fetch next 2 rows only;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('BOOKID..TITLE..publisher..Author');
    for i in c
        loop
            dbms_output.put_line(i.bookid||'..'||substr(i.title,1,
            10)||'..'||i.publishername||'..'||i.firstname||' '||i.lastname);
        end loop;
end;
/
```

I am getting error on this line "fetch next 2 rows only". Can u please explain & give me the correct solution. I want only first 2 rows from this.

ERROR-
limit 2;
*
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you running?

Comment: And exactly what _is_ the error?

Comment: please have a look now.

Comment: It seems you are not in Oracle 12c version and you have to use `rownum` concept here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `WHERE ROWNUM <= 2` instead.  It needs to wrap the original query so that the sorting is considered before it returns the first two rows.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c IS
        SELECT *
          FROM (  SELECT book.bookid,
                         book.title,
                         publisher.publishername,
                         author.firstname,
                         author.lastname
                    FROM book
                         INNER JOIN publisher ON book.publisherid = publisher.publisherid
                         INNER JOIN author ON book.author_id = author.authorid
                ORDER BY book.title)
         WHERE ROWNUM <= 2;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('BOOKID..TITLE..publisher..Author');

    FOR i IN c
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
               i.bookid
            || '..'
            || SUBSTR (i.title, 1, 10)
            || '..'
            || i.publishername
            || '..'
            || i.firstname
            || ' '
            || i.lastname);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```